# How to check the data in sql server if it is there for everyminute

Tags: sql-server

I have table with

> **fields**: Id, ChId, ChValue, ChLoggingDate

Now the data will be saved for everyminute in to the database. I need a query to check if the data exists for every minute in the table through out the year for a particular weekday. That is, all Monday's in 2013 if it has complete data for that day calculate the arithmetic mean for the year of Monday's.

Comment: Step 1:Get mindate and maxdate for a particular year.Lets say 2014.
Step 2:Find the first monday
Step 3:Get the record count for that day(60mins*24hours=1440). 
Step 4:If record count = 1440 then record exist for everyminute on that Monday. 
Repeat the above step for all other Mondays(by adding 7 to the first found Monday) till you reach the MaxDate. is this rite?

Answer (score 0):

YOu will need a table - or a table value function - to create a timestamp for every minute, then you can join with that and check where the original table has no data.

Only way - any query otherwise can only work with the data it has.

This is a common approach for any reporting.

http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/create-date-time-intervals-table-in-sql-server.aspx

explains how, you just must expand it to a times table. If you separate date and time you can get away with a time table (00:00:00 to 24:59:59) and a date table separately.